# I am getting 404 not found error when trying to enter URL'S manually in react

Tags: reactjs, web, react-router

I am getting a 404 error whenever I try to enter a URL directly in the browser whereas, the normal routing using react-router-dom works fine.

I have a nested routes structure with the nested routes being lazy loaded.

I have also read about a few potential solutions including hashrouter but it comes with the disadvantage of having a hash in the url

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Please post a code snippet to understand the problem better.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you've an issue with and where you are trying deploy your app. We can't help debug what we can't see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using React, it's important to understand that the app is only initially loaded when you call the index route (e.g. localhost:3000/), so if you're manually browsing to certain routes (e.g. localhost:3000/testroute), your browser is attempting to GET that specific route rather than loading the React application first.

I'd suggest checking out the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually), as it provides a very detailed explanation and potential solutions. On one of my React apps I encountered this issue and was able to resolve it with a DNS wildcard.